# Use previous value inside mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following table:

```
table<- data.frame(a = rep(100, 8),
                   b = seq(from = 0.2, by = 0.1, length.out = 8))
```

What I would like to obtain is following column c which has values:

1. For the first row, take a*b
2. For the second row, take previous row
   **c**, add it to the second row **a** and then multiply with **b**. Hence, ((100*0.2)+100)*0.3 = 36. This logic is then same for the
   rest of the rows. Hence, for the third row I would have: (100+36) *
   0.4 = 54.4.

I tried something like code below, but I cannot refer to the new column inside mutate.

```
table %>% mutate(c = (a + ifelse(is.na(lag(c), 0, lag(c)))) * b)
```

Some tips?

Thank!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: `table` is a poor name for a user variable, as it corresponds to a reserved base R function.

Here is a solution using a `for` loop.

(Just to preempt any `for` loop objections: We're not dynamically growing an object here, and are instead changing pre-initialised entries, so a `for` loop will be fast; that's not saying that there won't be any faster ways...):

```
# Initialise
df <- transform(df, c = a * b);

# Calculate c for rows 2..
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) df$c[i] <- (df$c[i - 1] + df$a[i]) * df$b[i];
df;
#    a   b        c
#1 100 0.2  20.0000
#2 100 0.3  36.0000
#3 100 0.4  54.4000
#4 100 0.5  77.2000
#5 100 0.6 106.3200
#6 100 0.7 144.4240
#7 100 0.8 195.5392
#8 100 0.9 265.9853
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = rep(100, 8),
    b = seq(from = 0.2, by = 0.1, length.out = 8))
```